# How to install pyenv download with venv plugin?

Tags: python, python-venv, pyvenv

I am a bit confused I want to install pyenv that works with venv. Do I first install pyenv  https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer then install https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv or just
install the second one?

Comment: as written in the `pyenv-virtualenv` readme, this is a plugin for pyenv. So you need to install pyenv first

Answer (score 0):

Yes, virtualenv is plugin. First install Pyenv, then install virtualenv by cloning the git repo into the plugins folder, using:

`$ git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv.git $(pyenv root)/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv`

If you're still confused just follow the directions here:
[Installation](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv#installation)